# Extending ImageView does not call onDraw

Tags: android, imageview

I extended the ImageView class (tried with View as well, same result)

I need to perform custom drawing, but its not happening.
The onDraw method is not getting called

How can I fix it ?

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CompasView extends ImageView {
    public CompasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context,attrs,defStyle);
    }

    public CompasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    Paint paint;
    int direction = 0;

    public CompasView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context,null,0);

    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int height = this.getHeight();
        int width = this.getWidth();
       Log.d("COMPASONDRAW","direction: "+direction + " width:"+width+ " height:"+height);
        canvas.rotate(direction, width / 2, height / 2);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public void setDirection(int direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
        this.invalidate();
    }

}
```

this is the xml file

```
 <com.myapp.widget.CompasView
                android:id="@+id/compasView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_between_adjacent_widgets_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/space_between_adjacent_widgets_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/compas" />
```

Orientation change logs:

```
07-28 17:47:54.060: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:176
07-28 17:47:54.130: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:173
07-28 17:47:54.190: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:166
07-28 17:47:54.260: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:156
07-28 17:47:54.320: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:143
07-28 17:47:54.390: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:134
07-28 17:47:54.450: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:127
07-28 17:47:54.510: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:123
07-28 17:47:54.580: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:117
07-28 17:47:54.640: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:108
07-28 17:47:54.710: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:98
07-28 17:47:54.770: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:95
07-28 17:47:54.830: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:96
07-28 17:47:54.890: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:99
07-28 17:47:54.960: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:101
07-28 17:47:55.030: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:102
07-28 17:47:55.090: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:105
07-28 17:47:55.150: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:108
07-28 17:47:55.210: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:110
07-28 17:47:55.280: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:112
07-28 17:47:55.340: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:114
07-28 17:47:55.410: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:116
07-28 17:47:55.470: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:118
07-28 17:47:55.530: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:120
07-28 17:47:55.600: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:121
07-28 17:47:55.660: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:123
07-28 17:47:55.720: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:124
07-28 17:47:55.790: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:125
07-28 17:47:55.860: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:126
07-28 17:47:55.910: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:128
07-28 17:47:55.980: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:128
07-28 17:47:56.050: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:129
07-28 17:47:56.100: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:130
07-28 17:47:56.180: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:131
07-28 17:47:56.240: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:131
07-28 17:47:56.300: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:132
07-28 17:47:56.370: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:132
07-28 17:47:56.430: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:133
07-28 17:47:56.490: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:133
07-28 17:47:56.550: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:134
07-28 17:47:56.620: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:134
07-28 17:47:56.690: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:135
07-28 17:47:56.740: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:135
07-28 17:47:56.810: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:136
07-28 17:47:56.880: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:136
07-28 17:47:56.940: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:136
07-28 17:47:57.000: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:137
07-28 17:47:57.060: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:137
07-28 17:47:57.120: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:137
07-28 17:47:57.190: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:138
07-28 17:47:57.260: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:138
07-28 17:47:57.320: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:138
07-28 17:47:57.390: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:138
07-28 17:47:57.450: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:138
07-28 17:47:57.510: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:138
07-28 17:47:57.580: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:139
07-28 17:47:57.640: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:139
07-28 17:47:57.710: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:139
07-28 17:47:57.760: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:139
07-28 17:47:57.830: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:139
07-28 17:47:57.900: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:139
07-28 17:47:57.960: D/COMPAS(25029): comaps orientation:139
```

the log inside ondraw

```
07-28 17:53:36.320: D/COMPASONDRAW(27007): direction: 195.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 17:53:36.390: D/COMPASONDRAW(27007): direction: 195.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 17:54:28.490: D/COMPASONDRAW(27007): direction: 108.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 17:54:28.510: D/COMPASONDRAW(27007): direction: 108.0 width:105 height:105
```

merged log output

```
07-28 18:00:26.990: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.050: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.060: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.110: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.120: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.170: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.200: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.250: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.250: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.310: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.320: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.370: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.380: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.440: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.440: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.490: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.490: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.560: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.560: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.620: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.630: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.690: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.710: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.750: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.750: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.820: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.820: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.880: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.880: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:27.950: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:86
07-28 18:00:27.960: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 86.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.000: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.030: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.070: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.070: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.140: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.150: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.200: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.210: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.260: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.280: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.320: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.320: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.390: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.400: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.460: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.470: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.520: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.530: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.580: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.600: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.640: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.650: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.710: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.720: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.770: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.790: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.840: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.860: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.900: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.900: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:28.960: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:28.970: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.030: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:29.030: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.080: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:29.100: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.160: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:29.160: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.220: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:29.220: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.280: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:29.300: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.350: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:29.360: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.400: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:87
07-28 18:00:29.410: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 87.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.470: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:89
07-28 18:00:29.480: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 89.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.530: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:95
07-28 18:00:29.550: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 95.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.600: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:101
07-28 18:00:29.610: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 101.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.740: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:113
07-28 18:00:29.740: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:120
07-28 18:00:29.750: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 120.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.790: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:124
07-28 18:00:29.800: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 124.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.860: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:128
07-28 18:00:29.870: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 128.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.920: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:132
07-28 18:00:29.920: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 132.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:29.980: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:134
07-28 18:00:29.980: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 134.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.050: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:134
07-28 18:00:30.050: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 134.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.100: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:134
07-28 18:00:30.120: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 134.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.170: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:134
07-28 18:00:30.180: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 134.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.230: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:133
07-28 18:00:30.230: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 133.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.300: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:133
07-28 18:00:30.310: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 133.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.370: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:133
07-28 18:00:30.380: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 133.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.430: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:132
07-28 18:00:30.440: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 132.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.480: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:133
07-28 18:00:30.500: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 133.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.550: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:136
07-28 18:00:30.560: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 136.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.610: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:142
07-28 18:00:30.620: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 142.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.680: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:155
07-28 18:00:30.690: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 155.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.740: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:172
07-28 18:00:30.770: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 172.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.810: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:189
07-28 18:00:30.810: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 189.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.870: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:198
07-28 18:00:30.880: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 198.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:30.940: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:199
07-28 18:00:30.950: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 199.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.000: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:195
07-28 18:00:31.020: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 195.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.060: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:193
07-28 18:00:31.060: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 193.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.120: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:192
07-28 18:00:31.130: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 192.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.190: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:190
07-28 18:00:31.210: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 190.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.250: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:189
07-28 18:00:31.270: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 189.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.320: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:187
07-28 18:00:31.320: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 187.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.380: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:183
07-28 18:00:31.380: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 183.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.440: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:180
07-28 18:00:31.450: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 180.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.510: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:177
07-28 18:00:31.530: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 177.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.570: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:174
07-28 18:00:31.590: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 174.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.630: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:171
07-28 18:00:31.650: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 171.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.700: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:168
07-28 18:00:31.710: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 168.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.760: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:166
07-28 18:00:31.770: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 166.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.820: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:163
07-28 18:00:31.850: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 163.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.890: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:161
07-28 18:00:31.890: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 161.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:31.960: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:159
07-28 18:00:31.960: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 159.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.010: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:157
07-28 18:00:32.030: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 157.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.080: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:155
07-28 18:00:32.090: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 155.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.140: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:153
07-28 18:00:32.140: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 153.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.210: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:152
07-28 18:00:32.220: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 152.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.270: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:150
07-28 18:00:32.280: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 150.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.340: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:149
07-28 18:00:32.360: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 149.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.400: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:147
07-28 18:00:32.410: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 147.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.470: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:146
07-28 18:00:32.470: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 146.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.530: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:145
07-28 18:00:32.530: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 145.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.590: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:144
07-28 18:00:32.600: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 144.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.670: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:143
07-28 18:00:32.690: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 143.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.720: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:142
07-28 18:00:32.740: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 142.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.780: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:141
07-28 18:00:32.800: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 141.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.850: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:140
07-28 18:00:32.850: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 140.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.900: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:140
07-28 18:00:32.910: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 140.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:32.970: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:139
07-28 18:00:32.970: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 139.0 width:105 height:105
07-28 18:00:33.030: D/COMPAS(28509): comaps orientation:138
07-28 18:00:33.040: D/COMPASONDRAW(28509): direction: 138.0 width:105 height:105
```

Comment: Can you also update your class and xml?

Comment: updated and this is some text to make the comment longer

Comment: so it appears onDraw is getting called.. is it just that the canvas is not rotating?

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Developers [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

Drawing is handled by walking the tree and rendering each view that intersects the invalid region. Because the tree is traversed in-order, this means that parents will draw before (i.e., behind) their children, with siblings drawn in the order they appear in the tree. If you set a background drawable for a View, then the View will draw it for you before calling back to its onDraw() method.

**Note that the framework will not draw views that are not in the invalid region.**

To force a view to draw, call invalidate().

This might also be helpful: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+ArpitMathur/posts/cT1EuBbxEgN

Comment: if you notice, invalidate is called when i call "setDirection" which in turn is set approx once every 2 seconds

Comment: can you include the rest of your code?  have you tried logging width, height, and direction in your onDraw?

Comment: i included the direction change from the compas, and what ondraw actually gets... for a gazilion updates from the compas fragment sensor, got only 4 updates in ondraw ?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to set the actual image for drawing? In your example you have only set `android:background`, but the background is not drawn in onDraw method. It's inherited from View and is drawn in View#draw(Canvas) method (the same method calls onDraw at some point after it has drawn background)

P.S. You also should wrap your manipulations to canvas with canvas.save()/restore() method calls in case someone will extend your component and will try to draw something (so they wouldn't get surprised by rotation)

Comment: 1. i changed background to src
2. i set canvas.save() and then canvas.restore() after i finished my draw routine, and still the view does not rotate...

Comment: I tried your code exactly as it is and it worked fine. I assume you have problems with setDirection. I would suggest you to try set default direction to 45 (or something) and silence setDirection, to test if it is the view that doesn't rotate. If view will get rotated then it's your other code that always sets the 0 as direction

Comment: the direction changes between 70 and 150

Comment: It doesn't matter for test. Can you guarantee, that setDirection is called with any digit except 0? Right now it looks like direction is always 0

Comment: i added the log of merged updates, there are a gazilion calls to both ondraw and the orientation change method, however, the view on the screen NEVER changes :(

Comment: I can't find out the reason without the rest of source codes (

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58181/discussion-between-lena-bru-and-alex-orlov).